# Overflow in HTML table cell

Tags: html, css

I have an issue I'm trying to solve about **table-cell** display and its content which make its parent width grow despite of table-cell fixed width and overflow defined.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8cevryh9/

```
<table border="3">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 20px">1</td>
        <td style="width: 80px; overflow:hidden;">
            <div style="width:200px">
                FAT CONTENT
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 30px">3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here 2nd cell is 200px width, I would have it stay 80px and the content overflow hidden. Anyone an idea ?

Comment: set a max-width not solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a width on the table, as well as the table-layout to fixed:

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 130px;
}
```

```html
<table border="3">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 20px">1</td>
    <td style="width: 80px; overflow:hidden;">
      <div style="width:200px">
        FAT CONTENT
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 30px">3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Didn't know this style attribute table-layout.